# How can I get Rails to give me more details on an error it's not logging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stack-trace

This has been stumping me: Rails is throwing this error, *after* it's finished rendering my views, but *before* it gets back to the browser:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `start_with?' for #<Proc:0x00005651bfe017f0>)
```

And... that's it. There's no stack trace. I get shown the standard 500 "We're sorry, but something went wrong" page, despite having `config.consider_all_requests_local = true` set. There are no further details either in the terminal or in `log/development.log`.

I can't find any Procs that it might be complaining about, nor can I find any calls to `start_with?` that might be the cause; I've gone back through Git history and isolated the issue to one commit ([this one](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/metasmoke/commit/2edeb7d1112f44787a5eb441b0405ea3abf16343), if you want to take a look in detail), but nothing within that commit jumps out as being obvious.

Calling a `render layout: false` *does* work, as does simplifying my `layouts/application.js` down to just a `<%= yield %>`, which makes me think it might be something in there, however - I made no changes to it *or any views at all* in the commit in which the issue appeared.

What I'd really like to know is how I can get Rails to give me the stack trace for this error, so I can figure out where it's coming from. If you have any ideas where the bug itself might be, those are more than welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

Drop this in an initializer (proc.rb):

```
class Proc
  def start_with?(*args)
    puts caller  
  end 
end
```